# set a filter of packet length in wireshark

Tags: wireshark, pcap, libpcap

I've capture a pcap file and display it on wireshark.
I want to analysis those udp packets with 'Length' column equals to 443.

On wireshark, I try to found what's the proper filter.

```
udp && length 443 # invalid usage
udp && eth.len == 443 # wrong result
udp && ip.len == 443 # wrong result
```

By the way, could the wireshark's filter directly apply on libpcap's filter?

Comment: How about using simply `udp.length==443`?

Comment: In answer to "the wireshark's filter can directly apply on libpcap's filter?", the answer is "no" - Wireshark display filters and libpcap capture filters are processed by different code and have different syntaxes and capabilities (Wireshark display filters are much more powerful than libpcap filters, but Wireshark is bigger and does a *LOT* more work to support that).

Answer (score 82, accepted):

All these work on Wireshark's filter

```
frame.len==243  <- I use this
ip.len==229
udp.length==209
data.len==201
```

Comment: The first of those is what should be used to filter on the Length column.

Comment: And the different lengths included are indicative of the nested protocols, e.g. IPv4 headers are usually 20 B (`ip.len - udp.length`).

Comment: Also of more general use is `len(<some field>) == <expected number of bytes>`