# filter the packets Wireshark with size

Tags: wireshark

I am trying to solve the below question:
filter the UDP packets having a size equal to 242 bytes.

I looked to this answer `udp.length==209` [set a filter of packet length in wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022710/set-a-filter-of-packet-length-in-wireshark), but instead of getting packets with length 209 bytes I get packets with length 243 bytes.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaKs9.png). can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

Your image shows a packet like

```
Frame 243 bytes
'-> Ethernet
'-> IPv4
'-> UDP
'-> Dropbox LAN Sync
```

Ethernet will be 14 bytes with 6 per src/dst MAC address and 2 bytes for [Ethertype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType).
The IPv4 header will be a [minimum of 20 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4), but could be more with options. It just so happens to be 20 here.

Eth 14 bytes + IP 20 bytes = 34 bytes

243 bytes - 34 bytes of Eth/IP = 209 bytes of UDP data